# DSE Graph - Do vertices with meta-properties require more than a single query to read?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

The [5.1.3 doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html#RNdse513__513Hgraph) says

> Vertices without multi-properties fetch all properties in a single
>   query, rather than requesting properties one at a time. Using
>   multi-properties as vertices is not recommended.

Is that true for **`meta-properties`** as well? In other words, are multiple queries needed to fetch vertices that have meta-properties or can a single query suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta-properties are fine.
The issue with multi-properties is that we can't have a good idea if an element is small or large. So fetching everything could be expensive.